# What are Gopis' views on Sri Krishna stealing their clothes?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

I see some atheists saying Sri Krishna possessed bad behavior since he stole the clothes of the gopis while they were bathing. (I DO NOT AGREE WITH THEM) They also say the gopies may not have liked it and they might have felt like their modesty was outraged when he stole their clothes.

I know Krishna was naughty and I don't know why exactly he stole their clothes. him stealing the gopis' cloths.
Now my question is since the gopis were humans How did they feel about this? What was their reaction? Did they feel like their modesty was outraged? Are there any verses that utter the reaction of the gopies?

**Please note, I have used the term "bad-behavior" from the perspective of the people using that term. I understand it might be offensive to use that term. But I had to use that term for clarification purposes. My intention is to get clarification.**

**Also note, I don't know the entire story of what happened there. So pardon me if I've got something wrong**

Comment: you are speaking about supreme being how could he bounded by gunas and fallacies of human.. second he wanted to teach gopis a lesson to prohibit them from taking nude bath in public place in those days it was common for gopis to take nude bath..

Comment: request you to change pervert like behavior in your question otherwise this may get closed or deleted for offensive post

Comment: For those who do not believe Krishna is God, it is a pervert like behavior. For those who believe Krishna is God, it is an instance of Krishna snatching away the ego of the jeevas (gopis).

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Not a place to show something right or wrong. Ask real questions and not to prove someone right or wrong. Your question should have emphasis but the note is getting unnecessary emphasis. Please ask real questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma please note I've edited the question

Comment: Refer to [my answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28994/3872) on the linked question, there is a significant reason why Sri Krishna did it, nothing to do with him being naughty or something like that.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria ok

Comment: @PrasannaR please note I've edited the question

Comment: @LazyLubber please note I've edited the question

Comment: @Destroyer I think this question deserves reopening as the question referred to is not about the views of the Gopis. Please check and do accordingly.